# how to customize the "Delete" button on swipe

Tags: iphone

How can I customize the "Delete" Button on swipe. I want to use the small button instead of using this Red Delete Button. I know how to change the title but I want to change the size and  image of button.Is it possible?

As I am new, I am not allowed to upload images.

Please help!

Comment: I believe without implementing a completely custom control and gesture, you can only change the text. As for the completely custom control, I can't help you with that...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not recommended. Apple likes consistency between all of its apps, so you should consider keeping it that way.